# Pyspark Py4JJavaError

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoMue.png)

Getting this error on - > sc = pyspark.SparkContext(appName="Pi") line

`import findspark
findspark.init()
import pyspark
import random
pyspark.SparkContext(appName="Pi")`

Comment: The master URL is not correct. The format for standalone is `spark://host:port`.

Comment: @user6910411 How do I change the Master URL ?

Comment: You'll have to find the place where you've configured it. Likely some configuration file. Maybe `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf`? Or you can set it explicitly when you create context `pyspark.SparkContext(naster="spark://host:port", appName="Pi")`

Comment: Error Message after defining master : @user6910411
'Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:559)
 at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)'